# Change DataLabel on Excel chart to "Missing Text"

Tags: vba, excel

The problem with the code below is this. I have a radar chart and a bar chart. I want a gap for a missing value for the radar chart, as a result, I need to delete the value in the cell to get the gap, however when I remove the cell value, the label goes missing for the bar chart. I have tried to create a new label and align it, but it does not work.

```
   Option Explicit

Sub ChangeChartText()
    Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
    Dim mySrs As Series
    Dim myPts As Points
    Dim ws As Worksheet, x, vals
    Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, p As Point, y, z

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.name, 4) = "Page" Then
            With ws
                'For Each myChartObject In ws.ChartObjects
                 '   For Each mySrs In myChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection
                        For y = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
                            Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(y).Chart
                            For z = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
                            Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(z)
                            vals = s.Values
                                For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                                   On Error Resume Next
                                    If Not s.Points(x).DataLabel.Text Is Nothing Then
                                        If IsEmpty(vals(x)) Then
                                                s.Points(x).HasDataLabel = True
                                                s.Points(x).DataLabel.Text = "N\A"
                                                With s.Points(x).DataLabel
                                                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlTop
                                                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                                                    .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
                                                    .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                                                    .Orientation = xlHorizontal
                                                End With
                                        ElseIf s.Points(x).DataLabel.Text = "N\A" And vals(x) <> 0 Then
                                                s.Points(x).DataLabel.AutoText = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Next x
                            Next z
                        Next y
                  '  Next mySrs
                'Next myChartObject
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the question? Or where's the error?

Comment: Error is occurring here ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).DataLabels(x).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange = "Missing Response"

Comment: Do you mean the `ElseIf vals(x) <> 0 And ActiveChart...` line ?

Comment: I have made some improvements to the code as I am actively working on the code.